# Upload multiple files in Azure Blob Storage from Linux

Tags: linux, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Is there a way to upload multiple files to Azure Blob Storage from a Linux machine, either using the terminal or an application (web based or not)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your interest – There are two options to upload files in Azure Blobs from Linux:

1. Setup and use XPlatCLI by following the steps below:

   - Install the OS X Installer from http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xplat-cli/
   - Open a Terminal window and connect to your Azure subscription by either downloading and using a publish settings file or by logging in to Azure using an organizational account (find instructions here)
   - Create an environment variable AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING and set its value (you will need your account name and account key):  “DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=enter_your_account;AccountKey=enter_your_key”
   - Upload a file into Azure blob storage by using the following command: azure storage blob upload [file] [container] [blob]
2. Use one of the third party web azure storage explorers like CloudPortam: http://www.cloudportam.com/. 
   You can find the full list of azure storage explorers here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2014/03/11/windows-azure-storage-explorers-2014.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `find` command with the `exec` option to execute the command to upload each file, as described here [as described here](https://chodounsky.net/2015/07/24/upload-files-to-azure-storage-with-azure-cli-on-mac/):

```
find *.csv -exec az storage blob upload --file {} --container-name \
CONTAINER_NAME --name {} --connection-string=‘CONNECTION_STRING’ \;
```

where CONNECTION_STRING is the connection string of your Azure Blob store container, available from [portal.azure.com](https://portal.azure.com). This will upload all CSV files in your directory to the Azure Blob store associated with the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer the commandline and have a recent Python interpreter, the Azure Batch and HPC team has released a code sample with some [AzCopy-like functionality on Python called blobxfer](https://github.com/Azure/blobxfer). This allows full recursive directory ingress into Azure Storage as well as full container copy back out to local storage. [full disclosure: I'm a contributor for this code]

Comment: I'm trying out blobxfer, but running into some problems uploading the data. Can you have a look and dispense some advice? It's located here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34480404/how-to-use-blobxfer-an-azcopy-variant-for-linux-to-transfer-files-from-local-m

Comment: Please use the github issues page directly instead of posting a specific question regarding blobxfer (as it's not directly related to the original question).